# If an application has a Patent Number dated 2000, is it certain that it was granted a patent?

Tags: uspublication

I can't find a patent number either through searches for the inventor or the device with the Publication Number. I can only find references to the Publication Number. Is this the same as the Patent Number?

Is it possible that it was never granted a patent?

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. The publication number is just the number given to the published patent aplication whereas the patent number is the number given to the application after it has been granted a patent.It is therefore possible that the application is still pending decision or, in case it has already been processed at the Patent Office, but was rejected. This would explain the non existence of a patent number.

Comment: Do they issue a notice that the application was rejected for a patent? And if a patent does exist, should it be relatively easy to find using the Publication Number?